# how to fix the failure of win11 22h2 upgrade?

Tags: windows-11

Upgrade failure:

[image: Upgrade failure]

It freezes here like the photo above when I update my Windows 11 to 22H2.

I have tried `scf /scanow`, `troubleboot`, `restart wuauserv`, but nothing works.

My windows edition is Windows 11 Enterprise and OS build is 22000.778.

Here is the `setuperr.log` that contains a lot of errors, but I can't understand it:

```
2022-07-02 11:50:50, Error                 CONX   Appraiser: ERROR,SdbpGetManifestedMergeStubAlloc,1017,SdbpGetMergeSdbsDisabled failed [c0000034]

2022-07-02 11:50:53, Error                 CONX   Appraiser: ERROR,SdbpGetManifestedMergeStubAlloc,1017,SdbpGetMergeSdbsDisabled failed [c0000034]

2022-07-02 11:53:50, Error                 CONX   Appraiser: ERROR,SdbpGetManifestedMergeStubAlloc,1017,SdbpGetMergeSdbsDisabled failed [c0000034]

2022-07-02 11:54:04, Error                 CONX   Appraiser: ERROR,SdbpGetManifestedMergeStubAlloc,1017,SdbpGetMergeSdbsDisabled failed [c0000034]

2022-07-02 11:54:20, Error                 CONX   aeinv: ERROR,_AttributesFromBOE,2079,AeComputeProgramIdentityHash failed [80070057]

2022-07-02 11:54:20, Error                 CONX   aeinv: ERROR,_AttributesFromBOE,2079,AeComputeProgramIdentityHash failed [80070057]

2022-07-02 11:54:20, Error                 CONX   aeinv: ERROR,File::SaveFileToCache,1264,File missing required attribute! GetProgramId: GetFilePath:c:\users\lenovo\desktop\zsu-1191289.exe CommandLine:"C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SetupHost.Exe" /Product Client /Install /Package /Priority Normal /Quiet  /ReportId 6F2E22A6-7FC7-4F8D-BF47-4C589289C0BB.1 /FlightData "NG:172AA3" "/CancelId" "C-d10a2ed9-a3f2-466e-b70b-df321fb1c966" "/PauseId" "P-d10a2ed9-a3f2-466e-b70b-df321fb1c966" "/CorrelationVector" "VGJaL6bdL0mRlImQ.16.2.2.3" "/ActionListFile" "C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a66c5d572ae275d47d8de71d0603d45d\ActionList.xml"  [0x80004005]

2022-07-02 11:56:01, Error                 SP     Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-500): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)
2022-07-02 11:56:01, Error                 SP     Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-1001): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)
2022-07-02 11:56:02, Error                            ITaskFolder::DeleteTask failed. hr = 0x80070002
2022-07-02 12:00:29, Error                 SP         Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-500): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)
2022-07-02 12:00:29, Error                 SP         Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-1001): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)
2022-07-02 12:00:30, Error                 SP         pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2022-07-02 12:00:54, Error      [0x080831] MIG        CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "script" attribute is mandatory. class Mig::CMXEMerge *__cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadMerge(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2022-07-02 12:01:52, Error      [0x080831] MIG        CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2022-07-02 12:04:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: BthMigLib: BthMig(V:2 T:1): This device is not a personal device, will check to see if authenticated
2022-07-02 12:04:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: BthMigLib: BthMig(V:2 T:1): This device is not a personal device, will check to see if authenticated
2022-07-02 12:04:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: BthMigLib: BthMig(V:2 T:1): This device is not a personal device, will check to see if authenticated
2022-07-02 12:04:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: BthMigLib: BthMig(V:2 T:1): This device is not a personal device, will check to see if authenticated
2022-07-02 12:04:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: BthMigLib: BthMig(V:2 T:1): This device is not a personal device, will check to see if authenticated
2022-07-02 12:04:26, Error                 SP         Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-500): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)[gle=0x000036b7]
2022-07-02 12:04:26, Error                 SP         Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-1001): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)[gle=0x000036b7]
2022-07-02 12:05:11, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2022-07-02 12:19:23, Error      [0x080831] MIG        CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2022-07-02 12:24:46, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2022-07-02 12:24:46, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
2022-07-02 12:24:46, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: offline key (new) = '$OFFLINE_RW_810A4DCA$SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\Bridge'
2022-07-02 12:24:46, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: query bridge presence key failed 0x139f, bridge present = 0
2022-07-02 12:24:47, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\schemacachehelpers.cpp(607)\shmig.dll!00007FFC53B65C8A: (caller: 00007FFC53B63E5F) ReturnHr(1) tid(428c) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。
    Msg:[Migrated key for Path $OFFLINE_RW_810A4DCA$SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema.Migrated for 32-bit hive not found ] 

2022-07-02 12:24:47, Error      [0x08038d] MIG            Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll", CLSID={43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6}, ThreadingModel=Apartment, ExceptionHandling=Default}. Error: 0x80070002
2022-07-02 12:24:47, Error                 SP             Error READ, 0x00000002 while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll,{43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6},Apartment,Default. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2022-07-02 12:24:56, Error      [0x080831] MIG        CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "script" attribute is mandatory. class Mig::CMXEMerge *__cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadMerge(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2022-07-02 12:24:58, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG        Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: 指定的路径无效。 [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]
2022-07-02 12:24:58, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG        Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: 指定的路径无效。 [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]
2022-07-02 12:25:15, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(821)\shmig.dll!00007FFC546DAF46: (caller: 00007FFC546DB17E) LogHr(1) tid(3efc) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。

2022-07-02 12:25:55, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(821)\shmig.dll!00007FFC62DCAF46: (caller: 00007FFC62DCB17E) LogHr(1) tid(3e10) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。

2022-07-02 12:25:58, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(819)\shmig.dll!00007FFC62DCAEE2: (caller: 00007FFC62DCB17E) LogHr(1) tid(3ef0) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。

2022-07-02 12:25:58, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(820)\shmig.dll!00007FFC62DCAF1C: (caller: 00007FFC62DCB17E) LogHr(2) tid(3ef0) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。

2022-07-02 12:25:58, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(821)\shmig.dll!00007FFC62DCAF46: (caller: 00007FFC62DCB17E) LogHr(3) tid(3ef0) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。

2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG            Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: 指定的路径无效。 [0x000000A1]
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error                 SP             Error WRITE, 0x000000A1 while gathering/applying object: Registry, HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC. Will return 0
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error                 MIG            Error 161 while applying object HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC. Shell application requested abort
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error      [0x08097b] MIG            Abandoning apply due to error for object: HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error                                Apply failed. Last error: 0x00000000
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error                 SP         pSPExecuteApply: Apply operation failed. Error: 0x0000002C
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error                 SP         Apply (machine-independent apply, offline phase): Migration phase failed. Result: 44, no specific error
2022-07-02 12:26:04, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Offline portion of machine-specific and machine-independent apply operations. Error: 0x8007042B[gle=0x000000b7]
2022-07-02 12:34:43, Error                 SP         Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-500): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)[gle=0x000036b7]
2022-07-02 12:34:43, Error                 SP         Failure while getting the known folder path for CSIDL_PRINTHOOD (S-1-5-21-699976177-3337373315-2759829575-1001): Win32Exception: 系统找不到指定的文件。 [0x00000002] class UnBCL::String *__cdecl Mig::CFacadeUser::GetKnownFolderLocation(class UnBCL::String *,int *,class UnBCL::String **)[gle=0x000036b7]
2022-07-02 12:46:49, Error      [0x080831] MIG        CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2022-07-02 12:49:42, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2022-07-02 12:49:42, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
2022-07-02 12:49:42, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: offline key (new) = '$OFFLINE_RW_810A4DCA$SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\Bridge'
2022-07-02 12:49:42, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: query bridge presence key failed 0x139f, bridge present = 0
2022-07-02 12:49:43, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\schemacachehelpers.cpp(607)\shmig.dll!00007FF942B55C8A: (caller: 00007FF942B53E5F) ReturnHr(1) tid(ab4) 80070002 系统找不到指定的文件。
    Msg:[Migrated key for Path $OFFLINE_RW_810A4DCA$SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema.Migrated for 32-bit hive not found ] 

2022-07-02 12:49:43, Error      [0x08038d] MIG            Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll", CLSID={43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6}, ThreadingModel=Apartment, ExceptionHandling=Default}. Error: 0x80070002
2022-07-02 12:49:43, Error                 SP             Error READ, 0x00000002 while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll,{43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6},Apartment,Default. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2022-07-02 12:49:52, Error      [0x080831] MIG        CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "script" attribute is mandatory. class Mig::CMXEMerge *__cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadMerge(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2022-07-02 12:49:53, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG        Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: 指定的路径无效。 [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]
2022-07-02 12:49:53, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG        Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: 指定的路径无效。 [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]
2022-07-02 12:50:06, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2022-07-02 12:50:06, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
```

Comment: You are aware that Windows 11 22H2 has not been released.  So unless your system is configured to receive Insider Preview builds that likely has something to do with it.  Is your system currently configured to receive Insider Preview builds? Your screenshot is a static image of a laptop screen with a logo. It isn't really helpful. Can you post the output log of SetupDiag for us? There is a registry key that indicates if your system is compatible with 22H2, I will try and find it..

Comment: What is the value of **RedReason** contained within `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\TargetVersionUpgradeExperienceIndicators\NI22H2`?

Comment: Run Lenovo System Updater and update all your drivers. I have a Thinkpad here running 22H2 and it is working fine. All the drivers on this machine are up to date.  Also check for legacy software that is not compliant with newest Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently on the latest release of Windows 11 : 21H2 (10.0.22000.778) from June 23, 2022.

The update to 22h2 is on the Release Preview Channel. You need to
join the
[Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/)
in order to have that update.

Note that by passing to the Insider channel, you become a beta-tester
for Microsoft, accepting and reporting all the glitches that you
encounter in this unstable version of Windows. It's your choice.

I suggest to wait for this version to become stable and to be
released via the normal channel.

Comment: I am not convinced that 0x80070002 is caused by the author’s system it configured to get Insider Preview builds. I suspect a deeper issue. One that cannot be determined by the current information provided by the author

Comment: @Ramhound: My guess is that he's trying to force an Inside update on non-Insider build.

Comment: That typically wouldn’t matter, because at the very least, it would only allow a clean install. Suspect something else, I have down in-place upgrades to WI builds before